# installing the GD 2 library on fedora linux

Tags: codeigniter, gd, fedora

Hi was trying the code igniter image manipulation and I saw that I needed GD2 library so I went ahead and installed it but I could not see it in phpinfo.
Could anyone please help me with this.

Any efforts will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the php-gd extension.  There's probably a package for your OS with almost exactly that name.